# Can't Find Regex Pattern To Pull Specific Column

Tags: regex

Looking for help on correct Regex Code to pull Invoice #, Date, Description, Gross Disc, & Net in separate groups.

Having difficulty finding pattern on the Description Column.

Sample of how far I got with my code is below also:

```
[0-9A-Z]+\s(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})+\s([A-Z0-9]+\s)
```

Sample Of Text String:

```
2020-06-11 Sample Vendor Page 1
A/P Remittance Advice
Direct Deposit 2020-06-11

Cheque # 10353 Vendor # 0828 Sample Company, ULC

Invoice # Date Description Gross Disc Net
===================================================================================
222036 2020-05-06 P2153664 11,237.62 .00 11,237.62
222054 2020-05-06 P2153894 6,582.17 .00 6,582.17
222160 2020-05-01 P2152759 50,895.56 .00 50,895.56
222166 2020-05-01 P2153663 28,046.09 .00 28,046.09
222249 2020-05-05 P2154421 6,030.03 .00 6,030.03
222417 2020-05-05 P2153893 17,676.57 .00 17,676.57
CR01BCFF 2020-06-08 MULTI MCBS 6,872.59- .00 6,872.59-
DM2005R105 2020-06-02 MAY 20 RTN,EXP,N/CH 79.60- .00 79.60-
DM2005R450 2020-06-02 MAY 20 RTN,EXP,N/CH 20.70- .00 20.70-
DM20065533 2020-06-05 VPFP PROGRAM FEES 556.93- .00 556.93-
==========================================
112,938.22 .00 112,938.22

Printed on 2020-06-11 at 13:35
```

Comment: Don't use '|' in a character group, that will match the character '|'. Just use: [0-9A-Z].

Comment: To create groups, wrap them in parentheses, like ([0-9A-Z]+)

Comment: Specify which Regex engine/programming language you're using, they are different.

Comment: @PoulBak Will be using the expression over in Uipath which I think is VB.net. Any ideas how to pull out a "Description"Column when the text is MAY 20 RTN,EXP,N/CH or RTN,EXP,N/CH as seen above without grabbing the numbers from the next column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the fact that the description is the only field that can contain spaces, you can match as much as possible space separated strings as long as there is 3 columns left.

---

Explanation:

- `\S` matches any non whitespace character.
- `^` matches beginning of string
- `.` matches any character.
- `+` match as much as possible.

here is a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5bA-Z%5cd%5d%2b%29+%28%5cS%2b%29+%28.%2b%29+%28%5cS%2b%29+%28%5cS%2b%29+%28%5cS%2b%29&i=A%2fP+Remittance+Advice%0d%0aDirect+Deposit+2020-06-11%0d%0a%0d%0aCheque+%23+10353+Vendor+%23+0828+Sample+Company%2c+ULC%0d%0a%0d%0aInvoice+%23+Date+Description+Gross+Disc+Net%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a222036+2020-05-06+P2153664+11%2c237.62+.00+11%2c237.62%0d%0a222054+2020-05-06+P2153894+6%2c582.17+.00+6%2c582.17%0d%0a222160+2020-05-01+P2152759+50%2c895.56+.00+50%2c895.56%0d%0a222166+2020-05-01+P2153663+28%2c046.09+.00+28%2c046.09%0d%0a222249+2020-05-05+P2154421+6%2c030.03+.00+6%2c030.03%0d%0a222417+2020-05-05+P2153893+17%2c676.57+.00+17%2c676.57%0d%0aCR01BCFF+2020-06-08+MULTI+MCBS+6%2c872.59-+.00+6%2c872.59-%0d%0aDM2005R105+2020-06-02+MAY+20+RTN%2cEXP%2cN%2fCH+79.60-+.00+79.60-%0d%0aDM2005R450+2020-06-02+MAY+20+RTN%2cEXP%2cN%2fCH+20.70-+.00+20.70-%0d%0aDM20065533+2020-06-05+VPFP+PROGRAM+FEES+556.93-+.00+556.93-%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a112%2c938.22+.00+112%2c938.22%0d%0a%0d%0aPrinted+on+2020-06-11+at+13%3a35+&o=m)
Notice that used the multiline flag. so that each line is treated as a separate string.

```
(?m)^([A-Z\d]+) (\S+) (.+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)
```

Comment: This worked for me Thank you. I just modified slight as it was bringing in a few unwanted lines at the top. Went with: ^([0-9A-Z]+) (\S+) (.+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)

Comment: Sorry This worked; but, when running your demo link there is still lines at the top coming in? I need to figure out how to only see the detail

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the patterns for the first two and last three columns, you may use

```
^\w+\s(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(.*?)(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$
```

Or, if you have to run it on a multiline block of text:

```
(?m)^\w+\s(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(.*?)(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\r?$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cw%2b%5cs%28%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5cs%28.*%3f%29%28%5cS%2b%29%5cs%28%5cS%2b%29%5cs%28%5cS%2b%29%5cr%3f%24&i=2020-06-11+Sample+Vendor+Page+1%0d%0aA%2fP+Remittance+Advice%0d%0aDirect+Deposit+2020-06-11%0d%0a%0d%0aCheque+%23+10353+Vendor+%23+0828+Sample+Company%2c+ULC%0d%0a%0d%0aInvoice+%23+Date+Description+Gross+Disc+Net%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a222036+2020-05-06+P2153664+11%2c237.62+.00+11%2c237.62%0d%0a222054+2020-05-06+P2153894+6%2c582.17+.00+6%2c582.17%0d%0a222160+2020-05-01+P2152759+50%2c895.56+.00+50%2c895.56%0d%0a222166+2020-05-01+P2153663+28%2c046.09+.00+28%2c046.09%0d%0a222249+2020-05-05+P2154421+6%2c030.03+.00+6%2c030.03%0d%0a222417+2020-05-05+P2153893+17%2c676.57+.00+17%2c676.57%0d%0aCR01BCFF+2020-06-08+MULTI+MCBS+6%2c872.59-+.00+6%2c872.59-%0d%0aDM2005R105+2020-06-02+MAY+20+RTN%2cEXP%2cN%2fCH+79.60-+.00+79.60-%0d%0aDM2005R450+2020-06-02+MAY+20+RTN%2cEXP%2cN%2fCH+20.70-+.00+20.70-%0d%0aDM20065533+2020-06-05+VPFP+PROGRAM+FEES+556.93-+.00+556.93-%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a112%2c938.22+.00+112%2c938.22%0d%0a%0d%0aPrinted+on+2020-06-11+at+13%3a35+&o=m)

Matches look like

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - four digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, two digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(.*?)` -  any amount of 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `(\S+)` - any 1+ non-whitespace
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(\S+)` - any 1+ non-whitespace
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(\S+)` - any 1+ non-whitespace
- `$` - end of string/line.